# KeyError: '\x00' when unpickling an object

Tags: python, pickle

I'm trying to run a software tool and have been getting an error that I've narrowed down to a problem loading a pickled file that's part of the tool. This is the pickled file: https://github.com/CostaLab/reg-gen/blob/master/data/fp_hmms/atac_paired.pkl

When I try to load it manually, I get the same error I get when trying to run the software itself:

```
>>> f = open('atac_paired.pkl', 'rb')
>>> pickle.load(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
KeyError: '\x00'
>>>
```

I get the same error opening the file without `rb`. I have been in contact with the developer, but he says everything is working fine for him, so it doesn't seem like a problem with the file itself. He stated he is using Python 2.7.5 while I'm using 2.7.17 (the software doesn't support Python 3). I'm not sure where to go from here. What could be different about my python installation that is causing this?

Comment: I didn't think you could specify the protocol when loading, only when dumping?

Comment: Yep you're right, I misremembered.

Comment: That file contains objects defined in custom modules - `rgt.HINT.hmm` is the one that kills my attempt to load it.  It's conceivable that this error could be caused by you having incompatible versions of those modules.